# How do I install PyAudio on Raspbian in Python 3.7?

Tags: raspberry-pi, python-3.7, raspbian, pyaudio

Is there a wheel called 'PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl'?

Comment: Have you tried pip install? It can probably try to build it from source if there is no wheel

Comment: I tried 'pip3 install PyAudio' and failed.

Comment: Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-m53ymb3c/PyAudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-kdwcfq58/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-m53ymb3c/PyAudio/

Comment: Mhh, can you install other packages with pip? You could also try the apt package python3-pyaudio http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/

Comment: This might make a difference if apt installs some dependency, for example, if you don't have gcc, a pip install will fail, apt will install it for you.

Comment: I tried  'sudo apt-get install python3-pyaudio'  just now and succeeded. But I tried this several times several hous ago and failed again and again and reinstalled the system again and again, he told me 'python3 (< 3.6) but 3.7.3-1 is to be installed' everytime except this time. Anyway it's been installed successfully now XD